# Add event listener in Vue3 on an async instance

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

To provide some background information, I previously worked as a React developer but have recently transitioned to using Vue3. Currently, I am attempting to attach an event listener to a web3 instance, but it doesn't seem like the correct approach.

I created an `useWeb3()` composable which looks like this:

```
const useWallet = () => {
  const chainId = ref(null)

  const web3 = useAsyncState(async () => {
    // do some async work
    return await fooWeb3Instance();
  })

  watch(web3.isReady, async (isReady) => {
    if (isReady) {
      return null;
    }
    chainId.value = await web3.state.value.eth.getChainId();
  })

  console.log(web3.state.value) // correct value
  console.log(chainId); // 1

  return {
    web3,
    chainId
  }
}
```

Now I want to add a global event listener on the `web3` instance to check when the `chainId` changes and update that value from the callback.

```
web3.currentProvider.on('chainId', (nextChainId) => {
  chainId.value = nextChainId;
});
```

Here I have two questions:

1. Would it be appropriate to utilize the 'watch' feature to update a 'ref' once the 'useAsyncState' process is completed? Alternatively, is there a more effective method to accomplish this task?
2. Where should I add the listener?

If it was a react application I would do the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (web3) {
    web3.on(...)
  }
}, [web3])
```

Comment: `console.log(web3.state.value) // correct value` - it's not outside a watcher. Otherwise it looks ok. A listener needs to be set where you have the access to the instance. If it's inside a watcher then that's it. Needs to be cleaned up, that's where a watcher becomes handy

Comment: Changing behavior: `watchEffect`; Result of change: `computed`

Comment: You can do it inside a watcher. There is also a way to stop watchers after the first run. I always recommend the [vueuse](https://vueuse.org) library for vue projects. It provides really helpful composables like for instance [`watchOnce`](https://vueuse.org/shared/watchOnce/). 
But in your case could you not set the event listeners directly inside `useAsyncState` before returning the instance?